# AWS - Execute Sharing of an AMI from a Java Servlet

Tags: java, servlets, amazon-web-services, amazon-ami

I want to implement a service for my customers which allows them to fill in a HTML form (with their user info, email for example). When submitting the form, a Java Servlet will store the details sent and will share an Amazon AMI and. The response of the servlet will be  a bookmark  URL to the AMI.

What is the right way of invoking AWS related commands from a Java Servlet?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Have you tried the [AWS SDK for Java](http://aws.amazon.com/sdkforjava/)? There are [three packages](http://docs.aws.amazon.com/AWSJavaSDK/latest/javadoc/index.html) dealing specifically with EC2. The key method you want is probably [`AmazonEC2Client.modifyImageAttribute`](http://docs.aws.amazon.com/AWSJavaSDK/latest/javadoc/com/amazonaws/services/ec2/AmazonEC2Client.html#modifyImageAttribute%28com.amazonaws.services.ec2.model.ModifyImageAttributeRequest%29) (or the [asynchronous class method](http://docs.aws.amazon.com/AWSJavaSDK/latest/javadoc/com/amazonaws/services/ec2/AmazonEC2AsyncClient.html#modifyImageAttributeAsync%28com.amazonaws.services.ec2.model.ModifyImageAttributeRequest,%20com.amazonaws.handlers.AsyncHandler%29)).

The alternatives would be to use the underlying REST [Query API](http://docs.aws.amazon.com/AWSEC2/latest/APIReference/Welcome.html) directly or to create a private local service that calls a [command-line tool](http://docs.aws.amazon.com/AWSEC2/latest/CommandLineReference/ApiReference-cmd-ModifyImageAttribute.html). I would go with the SDK.